# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java, scanner

```
int b = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Эклипс мне вот такую штуку выдаёт:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method close() from the type Scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статичный метод принадлежит классу, не статичный метод принадлежит инстансу класса.

Когда вы вызываете `close()`, вы получаете ошибку потому, что этот метод не ассоциирован с инстансом класса.

Comment: Он же должен автоматически ассоциироваться в любом месте класса, в котором вызывается сканер. Или я не прав?

Comment: Нет вы не правы. Вам неообходимо изучить основы ООП.

Comment: Спасибо, я пока еще не дошел до этого.

Comment: @Yotow прежде чем писать на ООП языке все же неплохо бы изучить основы ООП:)

Comment: На ООП можно и структурным программированием заниматься, но вы правы :) я еще до этого не дошел

Comment: @Yotow если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то пометьте мой ответ как верный. Для статистики сайта и порядка :)